# How to retrieve Wrapped BNB tokens sent to Ethereum Smart contract instead of Binance Smart Contract address?

Tags: transactions, transfer

Need desperate help from experts here.  I swapped my ETH coins to BNB first to buy some pre-ICO coins, but executed a contract in Ethereum network (accidentally forgot to create and transfer Binance Smart Chain network in my Metamask Wallet).

While I see the contract was a success in Etherscan, the recipient said to claim they did not receive my funds due to the wrong contract address.  My BNB coins were wrapped (WBNB) and successfully transferred with the gas fee used in ETH.

The receiver is asking to send it to Binance smart contract address as below:

Is there any way to either transfer/ link/ swap my BNB coins from Ethereum Smart Chain to Binance Smart Chain?  If not, can I get the WBNB coins sent back to my original Metamask wallet?

Transaction Hash: 0xd2858e616a0ca3a95bdbf0697fae9e55eca2c032a2887a91ceb99b84133c7d5c

Sent to:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xc5ccbd8d0e4c7ad3bd88239b0d02823fde827e57

Should have been sent to: https://bscscan.com/address/0xc5ccbd8d0e4c7ad3bd88239b0d02823fde827e57

Please help!
Gene

Comment: It is not easy, but there's a way to recover ethers, or tokens from that address. You will need the contract's deployer to deploy a recovery contract on Ethereum at the same address (only the deployer could do it).

Comment: Thanks...  who would be the deployer?  I mean who should I contact for deploying a recovery contract?

Comment: I've no idea, you are the one trying to interact with the contract. The contract isn't verified on bscscan so it has no contact information.